# My osclass links are working properly but returns 404 error when checked

Tags: http-status-code-404, google-search-console, broken-links, osclass

I have created used car website www.carsangrah.com using osclass.

Some links (http://www.carsangrah.com/buy-used-cars_maharashtra-r781510) are working perfect but returns broken link (404 error) when checked on http://validator.w3.org/checklink.

Google and Bing webmaster also showing as 404 error. I am not able to index these links in Google and Bing. Please suggest a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution got to  oc-includes/osclass/controller then search.php then find this

```
                if( count($aItems) === 0 ) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
            }
```

replace `if( count($aItems) === 0 ) with if( count($aItems) === -1 )`. 
that fixes

Answer (score 0):

Osclass by default if a search have 0 results it returns 404 status code, you don't want to search engines index pages without any useful content.

If a link, results on a search results page with listings, 200 status code is returned.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. Let me clear my questions. The provided is valid, its working i.e. no 404 error. Still google is showing crawl error due to 404.

Answer (score 0):

Ah that explains the 404 issues I am seeing. I am going to log this as and error as no listings returned does not mean 404 it means no listings. 404 is page not found which is clearly wrong as the server is delivering a html page from the server.